# Enabling preview-latex For All Modes

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I can use preview-latex successfully on any Tex buffer, and it works great.

I was wondering how I can enable previewing capability for *any* mode, such as Fundamental, or any other programming language modes. I tried this, and I get

```
TeX-region-create: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

I am especially interested in having this work for Ein mode, the ipython notebook mode. I tried previewing in this mode as well, and I get a complaint from Ein saying that the point at I am at is read-only.

http://tkf.github.com/emacs-ipython-notebook/

Thanks,

Comment: Likely this is impossible, as preview mode is tied to AUCTeX, i.e. uses it's API, which obviously only works when applied to LaTeX files.

Comment: It is possible, although my old method doesn't work for me right now. The preview .ps file is generated, but `gs` fails to generate .png files.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "preamble.tex" file, or your own LaTeX file, to your working directory, and set the `'TeX-master` variable to the path of your "preamble.tex" file. Also, set `'TeX-header-end` and `'TeX-trailer-start`. Basically, add the following to your mode hook:

```
(set 'TeX-header-end "^[^%\n]*\\\\begin *{document}")
(set 'TeX-trailer-start "^[^%\n]*\\\\end *{document}")
(set 'TeX-master "/path/to/preamble.tex")
(cd "/path/to/")
```

Content of `preamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I haven't checked this out recently, but it worked for me long ago. Let me know if you've made progress and I'll update my answer.